# Adding byte string into xml tree (*.vtu file format)

Tags: python, xml, vtk, binary-data

I'm trying to write out data into a `*.vtu` file format and it's quite easy to create the file structure using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt64">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="100" NumberOfCells="100">
      <Points>
        <DataArray Name="points" type="Float64" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="3" offset="0" />
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray Name="connectivity" type="Int32" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="1" offset="2408" />
        <DataArray Name="offsets" type="Int32" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="1" offset="2816" />
        <DataArray Name="types" type="UInt8" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="1" offset="3224" />
      </Cells>
      <PointData Scalars="1_temp" Vectors="3_force">
        <DataArray Name="1_temp" type="Float64" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="1" offset="3332" />
        <DataArray Name="2_pressure" type="Float64" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="1" offset="4140" />
        <DataArray Name="3_force" type="Float64" format="Appended" NumberofComponents="3" offset="4948" />
      </PointData>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
  <AppendedData encoding="raw">
    _XF@�Loû1q@�`@!?�V7^W@9�D�C�z@�b�d@���Y�b@�r
  </AppendedData>
</VTKFile>
```

However, I'm struggling with one bit.

According to the VTK documentation for an [UnstructuredGrid](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/VTKFileFormats/#unstructuredgrid) file:

> The appended data section begins with the first character after the underscore inside the AppendedData element. The underscore is not part of the data, but is always present. Data in this section is always in binary form, but can be compressed and/or base64 encoded. The byte-order of the data matches that specified by the byte_order attribute of the VTKFile element. Each DataArray’s data are stored contiguously and appended immediately after the previous DataArray’s data without a seperator. The DataArray’s offset attribute indicates the file position offset from the first character after the underscore to the beginning its data.

It's very easy to create the `AppendedData` element and `_` but I've no idea how to correctly add the binary data. Here's how I'm doing it so far:

```
    # Appended data
    AppendedData = ET.SubElement(root, "AppendedData")
    AppendedData.set("encoding", "raw")
    AppendedData.text = "_"+str(appended_data_binarydata)
```

And then I write out the file with this:

```
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(tree, space="  ", level=0)

    tree.write("filename.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

The problem with this is that it's not binary data now or even correct as the string conversion adds some extra characters (opening and closing byte string ticks - `b''`).

```
  <AppendedData encoding="raw">_b'`\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe2\x13\x7fv\xcfn\xde?mA\x01\ry\x18\xeb?,\xf1\xd3EM\xf7\xe8?\x9fn\x94\xf0\x99\xd6\xe5?\x1f\xec\xe7j8\xc7\xe5?
... \x81\xffNG\xf7\xd5?\x98\xc5\xa6C\xb3\xa0\xbf?@=\x9bcPc\xc0?'</AppendedData>
```

This is the proper `Base64` string that should come directly after the `_`:

```
b'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'
```

There must be an easy way of doing this as VTK is such a popular toolkit. I just don't know how to achieve this last step! I guess it won't be part of `ElementTree` since a `.vtu` file is not a standard `xml` format nowhen using appended data, but there surely is a way to achieve this easily in python!

Comment: just to clarify somethings i think of when i see your code

`tree.write("filename.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)` setups the `encoding` flag to `uft-8` - this is most likely why you're getting a `\0x00..` byte stream in the output. You could remove the `encoding` bit, but honestly, the easiest approach given from what i understand is to just use base64 here

`AppendedData.text = "_"+base64.b64encode(appended_data_binarydata)`

just remember to declare `<AppendedData encoding="base64">` in the xml aswell. programmatically or otherwise.

Comment: @Skarlett Thanks for the comments. I've just tried `AppendedData.text = "_"+base64.b64encode(appended_data_binarydata)` as suggested but that just throws a type error as it's not possible to join a string to a byte string: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`.  Using two byte strings  `AppendedData.text = b"_" + base64.b64encode(appended_data_binarydata)`  also raises a type error `TypeError: cannot serialize b'_YAkAAA.......`. I think I may need to do this in a 2 stage process? Write the "_" first and then immediately write the byte string to the file?

Comment: `AppendedData.text = "_"+base64.b64encode(appended_data_binarydata).encode('utf8')`